# Marking a project as unsupported

Tags: polymer-1.0, dart-polymer, polymer-elements

I keep seeing the [polymer_elements](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_elements) being described as 'unsupported' although development is occurring with it.

Does this means it is unsupported by Google? Please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/issues/47, this is just because the pub site shows the description from the most recent non-dev release version.

This package was revived recently and is in release candidate, so the pub page still shows the old deprecated description.